# Authentication error when trying to insert record into mongo collection

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

Following are the versions I am using:

Python == **3.6.4**

Mongo DB db version == **v4.0.0**

Pymongo Version == **3.7.1**

**Issue**

Using the same connection string I am able to perform the following operations on mongo db

a) Connect to DB

b) Fetch collection name

Format of connection string is `mongodb://<username>:<password>@localhost:27017/?authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1&authSource=<dbName>`

When I try to insert record into the same collection using the `collection.insert_one()` method I get the following error
`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed`.

I am able to insert record using the same user when using the mongo shell `db.insert` method.

Comment: possible, if you can share some part of the code, since everything you did seems right.